# Packaging a vb6 project with multiple files with the same name

Tags: deployment, vb6, packaging

I'm using Package & Deployment Wizard to package a VB6 project. However, I recently have added a third party library that depends on a directory of XML data files. These files are split into sub directorys and some of the sub directories contain files with the same name as files in other sub directories but they are different files. I can't change the name of the files because the third party library requires specific names and a particular directory structure. Package and Depolyment Wizard will not allow me to add files of the same name. What are the suggested solutions to this problem? I don't care whether it is within Package and Deployment Wizard or using a different packaging solution as long as it is reliable and preferably free.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite installer is InnoSetup - it's free and incredibly powerful:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

There is a page about installing the VB system files here:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?vb

Comment: +1 for Inno Setup, it is really powerful tool. There is also Visual Studio extension available (http://www.visual-installer.com) so you can work with Inno Setup scripts from VS.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the alternative from MS, Visual Studio Installer. It supports VB6 projects, creates MSI files and I believe it does not have the same limitations as PDW.

It's an old download and its location on the MS website has changed since then but I think it's [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5fbbc453-cd04-4562-a66e-5c21436e6f56) though.

[Usage instructions (devx.com via google)](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19893)

[Reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244938(VS.60).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I will second Alex,

I have been using Inno for VB6 projects for the last 5 years.

further to this i recomend using Istool which is an add-on to Inno. You can import the .lst files that VB6 package and deploy creates and it will create the Inno install for you. From here its easy to add files and change the install to your requirements. 
http://hubpages.com/hub/ISTOOL